# Dot product angles greater than 180

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, vectors

Am I correct in saying that the angle in a dot product can't exceed or be 180 because the angle is based on the law of cosines?

Comment: Dot product doesn't have much to do with laws of cosines. The angle between two vectors can take any value from zero to 360°. It is just convenient to take value less than 180°.

Comment: "The angle in the dot product" What angle is that? The angle between two vectors is almost always measured as angle angle from $0$ to $\pi$ radians (0 to 180 degrees) but it could be any value, including negative.

Answer (score 3):

Ah, the situation is that the dot product unambiguously computes the *cosine* of the angle between the vectors. It does not at all directly compute the angle itself... for which there would indeed be ambiguity or an issue of definition/convention, as you speculate. That is, the dot product computes
a value $c$, and it's up to you to decide how to determine an angle $\theta$ such that $\cos \theta = c$. (Yes, I know, many textbooks authoritatively declare that $\cos^{-1}$ takes values in a certain range, but that's just *convention*, not a mathematical fact: $\cos^{-1}$ is multi-valued...)

Answer (score 0):

Let's take two vectors, $a,b \in \mathbb{R^2}$, as you've pointed out:

$a\cdot b = b\cdot a= a_1b_1+a_2b_2 = |a||b|\cos \theta \implies \theta = \arccos \left(\frac{a\cdot b}{ |a||b|}\right) \in [0,\pi]$

Concretely, if $a=[1,0],\;b=[1,1]$ then $|a|=1,\;|b|=\sqrt{2}\;$ and we get

$a\cdot b = 1 \implies \theta = \arccos\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right) = \frac{\pi}{4} \text{rad}$ or $45\deg$ -- this is the smaller of the two possible angles, with the other being $\frac{7\pi}{4}$ or $315 \deg$.

So we can see that the above formula for $\theta$ will give us the smallest *unsigned* angle between the vectors. As given by the other answer, this a bit of convention.

Answer (score 0):

One common approach:

First, define $\arccos$ to be the inverse of $\cos|_{[0,\pi]}=\cos|_{[0,180^\circ]}$ (the restriction of $\cos$ to $[0,\pi]=[0,180^\circ]$, i.e. the function that is the same as $\cos$ but with that domain).

Next, define the angle between two vectors $\mathbf u$ and $\mathbf v$ to be $\arccos \frac{\mathbf u \cdot \mathbf v}{|\mathbf u||\mathbf v|}$. (This definition can indeed be motivated by the Law of Cosines.)

Now, so defined, any angle will indeed be in $[0,\pi]=[0,180^\circ]$.